# Accessing instance methods in Eco templates using Marionette.js

Tags: javascript, templates, marionette, backbone-views, eco

I have simple controller

```
@Blobber.module "PlacesApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  Show.Controller =

    showPlace: (place) ->
      showView = @getShowView place

      App.mainRegion.show showView

    getShowView: (place) ->
      new Show.Place
        model: place
```

and view files:

```
@Blobber.module "PlacesApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Show.Place extends App.Views.ItemView
    template: "places/show/templates/_place"
```

I would like to access a method on my `place` model instance called `place.posts()`, which returns the associated `Collection` of the model `Post` via Supermodel.js  (http://pathable.github.io/supermodel/). I'm using Eco templates  (https://github.com/sstephenson/eco) and have been following the patterns in the tutorials at http://www.backbonerails.com.

Anyone know how I should go about accessing the associated `posts` in my Eco template? Preferably I'd like to be able to access the actual method `.posts()` but I would settle for creating a `posts` variable in my view and passing that into the template.

Thanks and if you need any more info, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do such thing in either of these two ways:

1. override `serializeData()` in `Show.Place` view, include `posts()` data in result json, then access the posts data in template by `@posts`.
2. override `templateHelpers()` in the view, and access the posts data in template by `@posts()`.

Check https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md for more info.

Comment: As far as I can tell, inside of the `templateHelpers` method, I still only seem to have access to the model attributes. Could you show some example code for one of these solutions? I don't know how to access the model at all in the `serializeData` method and I only know how to access the model attributes in the `templateHelpers` method.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, I'm open to using a `compositeView` or any other type of view that would be better for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **CompositeView** from Marionette to extract your logic from the template, it can handle a model and a collection:

So you'll have a template for the **CompositeView** without loop logic, in this view you must define an **itemView** and an **itemViewContainer** which will contain occurrence(s) of **itemView** binded to the models from your collection. After that you'll have to create the **ItemView** for your **CompositeView** with its own template.

I'm sure you'll find all the information you need with better explanations in the documentation ;)

[Marionette.CompositeView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md)